# Meaningless initialization of local variables

Tags: c, initialization, divide-by-zero

Does it makes sense to always initialize variables to some meaningless value like zero?

I have a co-worker that religiously initialize all variables to zero even in cases that zero would cause a problem, like this:

```
/* assume all arrays came with same length, not null and size > 2 */
void gradient ( float * result, const float * y, const float * t, const size_t size )
{
    float num = 0.0f;

    /* initialization of denominator to zero doesn't make any sense to me */
    float den = 0.0f;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < (size-1); i++ )
    {
        num = y [ i + 1 ] - y [ i ];
        den = t [ i + 1 ] - t [ i ];

        result [ i ] = num / den ;
    }

    num = y [ size - 1 ] - y [ size - 2 ];
    den = t [ size - 1 ] - t [ size - 2 ];

    result [ size-1 ] = num / den;
}
```

In the exemplified case, I proposed to at least initialize `den` to some `MAX_FLOAT` value. Am I wrong? Why some people believe this?

Comment: Wouldn't `float den = 1;` be better? And anyway it would be wise to check its subsequent value before committing to division.

Comment: Isn't there even a warning for initializing/assigning values to variables that can never be used?

Comment: Is initializing a variable to a value that is wrong for your program any better than not initializing it at all? What difference would it make to you if your program prints “3” for the result instead of “7” when the correct result is 1? In some case, yes, it is better. Floating-point values can be initialized to NaN (`NAN`), and then ordinary operations with them will produce NaN results, revealing that the program has performed incorrectly, which is better than using some non-NaN value resulting from lack of initialization. In other cases, maybe initialization is not helpful…

Comment: … One example is where the compiler would produce a diagnostic message alerting you that a variable is not initialized, but initializing it suppresses that message, along a bug to go undiscovered.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I've never considered this, but It seems interesting. I also found interesting the use of ```NAN``` in some cases.

Comment: Typo correction: “along a bug to go undiscovered”➝“allowing a bug to go undiscovered.”

Comment: Could setting last item be replaced with `result [ size-1 ] = result [ size-2 ]`?

Comment: @tstanisl that was clever. It is equivalent in this case.

Comment: @Sam, Side issue: why is parameter `size` made `const`, yet `result, y, t` are not `const` as in `void gradient ( float * const result, const float * const y, const float * const t, const size_t size )`?  All 4 parameters do not change. Or maybe simplify all to the tidy `void gradient(float * result, const float *y, const float *t, size_t size)`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, the inconsistency it is true. If have to do something I would increase the level of const qualification using ```float const * const```. In the proposed example I have the minimum level I need to avoid common errors like modifying the content of ```y, t``` and also adding ```const``` to the size in order to remember how much I rely in this boundary to do not perform out of bound access.

Comment: @Sam, Note that `const parameter` may be useful for the coding the function _definition_ (the .c file).  In a _declaration_ (.h  file), the caller of the function has no benefit, just noise.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I had no idea, I thought I have to match perfectly declaration and definition, thanks.

Comment: @Sam To be clear: `int f(const some_type * const ptr)` matches `int f(const some_type * ptr)`.  The 2nd `const` is optional. The first `const`, still needed, is part of the type of the reference object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case where initialization is not needed, it often hints that the declaration is too early (Although not always).

In this case I would always initialize, yet defer the declaration until needed.

```
/* assume all arrays came with same length, not null and size > 2 */
void gradient ( float * result, const float * y, const float * t, const size_t size ) {
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < (size-1); i++ ) {
        float num = y [ i + 1 ] - y [ i ];
        float den = t [ i + 1 ] - t [ i ];
        result [ i ] = num / den ;
    }

    float num = y [ size - 1 ] - y [ size - 2 ];
    float den = t [ size - 1 ] - t [ size - 2 ];
    result [ size-1 ] = num / den;
}
```

---

In case where I need the the index after a `for()` loop, I like the `for` loop to do the first assignment with no prior initialization.
I like the regular syntax of `int i; for (i=0; i<n; i++)` vs. `int i = 0; for ( ; i<n; i++)`.

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<n; i++} {
  ...
  if (...) break
  ...
}

// Do something with `i`
```

---

In cases where an object lacks a *needed* initialization, good compilers warn about such.  Always initialization and with a foolish value can hide bugs.  [@tstanisl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649133/meaningless-initialization-of-local-variables/76649347?noredirect=1#comment135137807_76649347) [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649133/meaningless-initialization-of-local-variables/76649347?noredirect=1#comment135137415_76649133)

It is that past (and current weak) compilers contributed to this "always initialize" goal, hence why some people believe this today.  It is less relevant today.

---

In other cases, code for what is most clear and set aside the *always* rule about unneeded initialization.

Comment: Thanks. It is true that I'm in my new job in the industry of Aircraft Safety Critical Software, my mentor suggests to me, it is good practice to declare all variables needed by the function at the beginning. But I'm not sure if this "rule" is the standard in this industry or just a misconception. Anyway, I agree with you.

Comment: @Sam Useful to learn from the old farts (they cheat).  After 5-10 years, you will know when to relax _always_ rules.  When in doubt, code for clarity.

Comment: @Sam, sometimes it is better to leave value undefined rather than filling with a garbage value. Modern sanitizers will detect usage of undefined values while they won't detect using garbage values

Comment: @Sam As I do not trust assumptions like `size > 2`, especially when good alternatives exist:  Note the subtle bug in for `( size_t i = 0; i < (size-1); i++ ) {` versus the better `for ( size_t i = 0; i + 1 < size; i++ ) {` and `size == 0` and latr code too. Sometimes such discussions about style issues fail to leave enough time for good code review.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thanks, You reveal some interesting bug that I made. The code is not production code, it was a simplified version prepared to launch the question, but I assume I din't catch that ```size-1```

Comment: @sam The bigger thing to learn is that any time/effort spent in one aspect of code writing/review takes away from others.  Heed the "code for clarity" goal.  Use that first in  choosing between competing paradigms - whatever the issue.